# Are English 'butterfly', German 'Butterfliege' and Dutch 'botervlieg' cognates?

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, borrowing

Yesterday the question was raised [why many languages do not share a root for 'butterfly'](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1282/444). When we look at the etymology of the English word, parallels are drawn to Dutch and German forms (OED):

> OE buttorfleoge, ME buterfliȝe, ME boterfleȝe, -flye, botter-,
>   bottir-, botyrflye... Etymology: < butter n.1 + fly n.1; with Old
>   English buttorfléoge compare Dutch botervlieg , earlier botervlieghe ,
>   modern German butterfliege . The reason of the name is unknown:
>   Wedgwood points out a Dutch synonym boterschijte in Kilian, which
>   suggests that the insect was so called from the appearance of its
>   excrement.

Are these forms true cognates, or are there other explanations? Maybe involving loan translations and/or spreading of particular beliefs about butterflies - e.g. that 'witches transformed themselves into butterflies to steal cream' - or independent coinings (because butterflies are/were attracted to the butter/dairy producing process)?

More forms (via [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butterfly#English)):

- Old English *butorflēoge*, *buttorflēoge*, *buterflēoge*
- Middle English *buterflie*, *butturflye*, *boterflye*
- Middle Dutch *botervliege*
- Modern German *Butterfliege*

But also:

- Middle Dutch *boterschijte* 'butter shitter'
- Middle High German *Molkendiep* 'milk-thief'
- Modern German *Molkendieb* 'milk thief'; and Low German *Botterlicker* 'butter licker'

These latter names are similar in meaning, but different in form - can that be taken as support that naming practices (i.e. cultural factors) were important in this case? (Similarly modern German *Schmetterling* < Schmetten 'cream').

Comment: As much as I'd be interested, I doubt there is an answer beyond the usual sources like dictionaries. But I do hope somebody finds some research where the term "butterfly" happens to be included. :P

Comment: Generally questions for one single etymology (especially of English) are frowned upon on this SE. Try English Language and Usage; though again you probably won't hear anything new.

Comment: FWIW, the OED says: OE buttorfleoge, ME buterfliȝe, ME boterfleȝe, -flye, botter-, bottir-, botyrflye... (Show More)

Etymology:  < butter n.1 + fly n.1; with Old English buttorfléoge compare Dutch botervlieg , earlier botervlieghe , modern German butterfliege . The reason of the name is unknown: Wedgwood points out a Dutch synonym boterschijte in Kilian, which suggests that the insect was so called from the appearance of its excrement.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this was relevant here, as I'm interested in whether these are cognates or perhaps loan translations, and if there's any reconstructed forms (something beyond the OE form).

Comment: arjan, the question is interesting and on-topic, since you are looking for cross-linguistic relationships. Also, from your comments, I see you are approaching the problem from a historical perspective. But the question, as phrased, makes it seem like you are merely looking for the etymology of a single English word. The downvotes are probably because of this. Thus, I suggest you to rephrase the question so as to make its linguistic aspects more evident.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus on the matter of cognacy (or alternative explanations for the similar forms).

Comment: I can't find the word "Butterfliege" in my German dictionaries. All I've been able to find is "der Schmetterling" (an insect) and "der Butterfly" (swimming). Also, why are you comparing words belonging to different time periods (OE, Middle Dutch, and Modern German)?

Comment: Perhaps 'Butterfliege' is actually outdated, or dialectal? But it's in the OED entry, I didn't look it up in a dictionary. I don't mean to compare Old English to Modern German forms as if they were established cognates. Explaining where 'Butterfliege' (if it exists) comes from is exactly part of the question. The context of all these other words that also contain the word for 'butter', 'milk' or 'cream' seems relevant.

Comment: Bosworth's 1838 A Dictionary of the Anglo-Saxon language gives "buttor-fleoge, _Plat. (Plat-dutch)_ Better-flege, _Dut. Kil. (Dutch, from Kilian)_ Butor-vilege". I don't know if it will be possible to determine if these were borrowings, calques, or congates. These are all West Germanic languages spoken in a fairly small area that probably didn't have abrupt transitions between languages.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: since it's hard getting any more decisive evidence, I'd accept this as an answer (for now). I suppose if we had good  reasons to believe that the specific cultural beliefs related to the name were already present before the divergence of West-Germanic, cognacy would be most likely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bosworth's 1838<sup>1</sup> *Dictionary of the Anglo-Saxon Language* gives "**buttor-fleoge**, *Plat*. (Plat-dutch) Better-flege, *Dut*. *Kil*. (Dutch, from Kilian) Butor-vilege".

I don't know if it will be possible to determine if these were borrowings, calques, or cognates. These are all West Germanic languages spoken in a fairly small area that probably didn't have abrupt transitions between languages.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Note, The 1838 Bosworth is [available online](http://www.archive.org/stream/adictionaryangl02boswgoog#page/n6/mode/2up) but the scanner cut off part of the page in question. The later Bosworths don't give the same cognate information.</sup>